# unistd.h implementation

Tags: linux, porting, realview

My toolchain (Realview) does not have implementation of `unistd.h`, I have a code that I need to use that **is** using `unistd.h`, some function like `access`, `open`.

So I need to implement this functions by myself.

My question is, is there another alternative or some reference (except the function description, found [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html)) that I can use in order to port/implement these functions?

What is the correct way to do that? It's my first time posting.

Answer (score 1):

The "function description" you link to has the page title "The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6", which indicates that it's perhaps a bit more of a heavy-weight than just being a mere description.

If you implement a function that fulfills all the text on that page correctly, chances are you've managed to re-implement it in a compatible way, so that programs complying to the same standard will build and work.

Not sure what else you feel you would need.

Comment: Okay,So what you are saying is that following the specification and re-implement the needed function is the way to go?